# pandas df seems not showing histogram, though data seems to be numeric

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, numeric

I have the following data:

```
23345355,USA, ,1/8/2016,5411,  ,18.31, ,95448
268035111,USA, ,1/8/2016,5921,  ,15.22, ,90266
35940332,USA, ,1/26/2016,5651,  ,121.94, ,91306
4211391,   , ,12/31/2015,0,  ,44.40, ,     
319878537,USA, ,12/29/2015,5814,04,0.86, ,90029
117039647,ESP, ,1/2/2016,3535,  ,372.38, ,08019
246311053,USA, ,1/11/2016,7523,  ,1.50, ,11101
953217,USA, ,1/29/2016,5968,  ,29.70, ,95032
270542768,USA, ,1/17/2016,7832,  ,18.30, ,40503
42855400,   , ,1/6/2016,0,  ,50.00, ,     
190065824,   , ,12/31/2015,0,  ,120.00, ,     
243492296,USA, ,1/25/2016,5331,  ,6.89, ,40810
102483965,US , ,12/31/2015,5814,  ,25.00, ,19341
```

I want to look at the last column, and do a histogram, so, I did (df is the pandas df)

```
df = df[df[LAST_COLUMN].apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
```

This way I cleaned up the elements that are not numeric (which I checked and worked).

However, when I do a df.hist(), I get histograms only for columns 0,4 and 6, not for column 8 (LAST_COLUMN). It looks like some element is not numeric, but I checked and they all are numeric.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You last column won't be of type `int` because `08019` isn't implicitely considered a int. Call `astype(int)` against that column for convert it into int.

Comment: You re right, they were treated as strings. Why did the check isnumeric() returned true, though?

Comment: The lambda is calling [isnumeric](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) against x that is a string object in that context. It's the python function returing true if all characters of the string are numeric, which is true.

Comment: Thanks, I thought isnumeric() would tell me if something is a number, my bad. I guess there is no function that does that, is there?

Comment: Actually in pandas you would check this property against the column and make sure the type of the column is a number, float or int